# Implementing Recursive Function with Async and Await with Angular 10

Tags: angular, async-await

I am trying to fetch a set of images as base64. To utilize max bandwidth, we planned to fetch one image after the other.

Below is the code

```
const input = ['url1']; //Array of image urls

this.recursiveFunction(input, 0, []).then((res: any) => {
    console.log(res);
});

async recursiveFunction(urls: any, index = 0, responses: any = []){
    const url = urls[index];
    return await this.srv.getData({ url: url }).subscribe((response: any) => {
        responses.push(response);
        if (responses.length !== urls.length) {
            return this.recursiveFunction(urls, index + 1, responses);
        }
        return responses;
    });

}
```

Tested with 6 images, the service calls are working fine.

But i see the console.log(res) outputs immediately the function is called (before the first service call) and is shown as below

[image]

The responses are having all 6 images base64 data. How to fetch the responses at the end of the last service call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method to :-

```
async recursiveFunction(urls: any){
    const url = urls[index];
    return await getImages(urls);
}



async getImages(urls: any) {
       const responses = [];
       for(const url of urls) {
        const res = await this.srv.getData({ url: url }).toPromise();
        responses.push(res);
       }
       return responses;
   }
```

now you can just pass array of urls and you will get images in response.

Comment: you should use current one, its more efficient and more clean.

Comment: Sure. I will replace this code while refractoring. This is for demo approval.

Comment: I was getting this error on recursive function resolve(await(...))  "'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules."

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene have updated the answer, now you shouldn't get the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use async and await, you can use switchMap and tap

```
myfunction(index){
    return index<this.data.length?this.obs$(index).pipe(
       tap(res=>this.res[index]=res),
       switchMap(_=>{
         index++;
         return this.myfunction(index)
       })):of(null)
    
  }
```

Just only need subscribe to myFunction

```
 ngOnInit(){
    this.myfunction(0).subscribe()
  }
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gdng4v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)